# Using wrapRootElement to provide context in GatsbyJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks, gatsby

I'm trying to add a dark mode toggle to a GatsbyJs app with the following approach:

Use Gatsby's `wrapRootElement` api to wrap the app in a context provider:

```js
// gatsby-browser.js

import ThemeProvider from '@components/themeProvider';
import Layout from '@components/layout';

export const wrapRootElement = data => <ThemeProvider {...data} />;
export const wrapPageElement = data => <Layout {...data} />;
```

Initialise the default theme from either localStorage or the user's browser settings:

```js
// themeProvider.js

const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  darkMode: false,
  toggleDarkMode: () => {},
});

const ThemeProvider = ({ element }) => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useLocalStorage(
    'darkMode',
    window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)').matches
  );

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ darkMode, toggleDarkMode }}>
      {element}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};
```

and finally the `layout` component: (note the console log)

```js
// layout.js

const Layout = ({ element }) => (
  <ThemeContext.Consumer>
    {({ darkMode }) => {
      console.log({ darkMode });
      return (
        <App theme={darkMode ? themes.dark : themes.light}>
          {element}
        </App>
      );
    }}
  </ThemeContext.Consumer>
);
```

This works apart from one issue. On initial load with a saved state of `true` (i.e. darkMode is on) the app renders the light theme instead. The console log above renders the correct `true` value, but the app does not render the right theme.

If I then toggle twice, setting the theme value from `true -> false -> true`, then darkMode shows correctly - so the logic is working as expected except for when the page first loads.

I believe this has something to do with Gatsby server side rendering the app with the default `false` state set in the `createContext` call in `themeProvider.js` but I'm unsure how to resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a working solution I came up with. The two key elements are;

1) the render block check in the context provider `{typeof darkMode === 'boolean' && element}` which prevents the page components rendering without a theme which would cause errors in styled components

2) the `useEffect` hook in the the hook which prevents the theme value from loading until the component has rendered client side and localStorage is available.

```js
// ThemeContext

import useTheme from '@hooks/useTheme';

const ThemeContext = React.createContext({
  darkMode: null,
  toggleDarkMode: () => {},
});

const ThemeWrapper = ({ element }) => {
  const [darkMode, setDarkMode] = useTheme(null);

  const toggleDarkMode = () => {
    setDarkMode(!darkMode);
  };

  return (
    <ThemeContext.Provider value={{ darkMode, toggleDarkMode }}>
      {typeof darkMode === 'boolean' && element}
    </ThemeContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ThemeContext;

export { ThemeWrapper };
```

```js
// useTheme hook

export default initialValue => {
  const [storedValue, setStoredValue] = useState(initialValue);

  useEffect(() => {
    const storedState = getItem(storageId);
    const query = window.matchMedia('(prefers-color-scheme: dark)');

    if (typeof storedState === 'boolean') {
      setStoredValue(storedState);
    } else {
      setStoredValue(query.matches);
    }
  }, []);

  const setValue = value => {
    setStoredValue(value);
    setItem(storageId, value);
  };

  return [storedValue, setValue];
};
```

Answer (score 1):

When a user open your Gatsby site you need to trigger your theme functionality. Since the local storage is empty on first visit, you only get the theme you want switching twice because only there is the theme mode determined.

You need to determine whether the user wants light or dark when first visiting the site.

Add a function to your Theme Provider class:

```
const determineThemeMode = () => {
  // depending on user settings, set the right theme mode
}
```

Trigger this new function either on [client entry](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onClientEntry), [client render](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onInitialClientRender), or [onInitialClientRender](https://www.gatsbyjs.org/docs/browser-apis/#onInitialClientRender). You probably only need to trigger it in one function. Try all at first and then eliminate.

---

As an alternative, there are plugins like [gatsby-plugin-dark-mode](https://github.com/insin/gatsby-plugin-dark-mode).

Comment: Thanks for your reply, it set me on the right path. I ended up using the theme provider and localStorage hook together to get the theme on load. I'll post the solution I came up with here